# Node.js w/ Apache, same IP, different ports. Virtual Host config breaks normal Apache (Site on 80) access?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, ubuntu-12.04, node.js

We have clients who don’t want to open port 3000 on their firewall and our app uses that port for Node.js.

Been trying to find a way to redirect port 3000 (node.js) traffic so we can bring our site up only using the domain name.  We also run Apache on the same box.  Ubuntu on AWS.

I mostly have it working now but am missing a small piece of the puzzle:  It now works with a port 3000 redirect to node, but I think in enabling this, I somehow have messed with the regular traffic working to the apache root. (80 and 443 no longer to to apache.)  Using 3000, node responds as expected in both http and https.)

BEFORE this change, we would test node this way:

app.company.net:3000/api/test (https)

and it would return:

'{"status":401,"message":"Invalid Token or Key"}' which is expected

Current problem:

- app.company.net/ <--DOES NOT WORK, brings up '{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}' should bring up portal. (http)
- app.company.net/ <--DOES NOT WORK, brings up '{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}' should bring up portal. (https)
- app.company.net/api/test <--WORKS, brings up '{"status":401,"message":"Invalid Token or Key"}' which is expected. (http)
- app.company.net/api/test <--WORKS, brings up '{"status":401,"message":"Invalid Token or Key"}' which is expected. (https)

I have installed and configured mod_proxy in apache and my redirect in my httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName app.company.net
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I comment out the above, the reverse happens.  Apache serves all, but I cannot get node to respond without appending :3000 to the url.

Also tried commenting out ALL of the above and messing with mod_rewrite, but that is it's own rabbit hole.  No luck after hours of messing with it.  I keep getting errors with /api/test not existing on the server.  That should probably be another ticket, though.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

-P

Comment: Are there any redirects in your node.js code for `/` ? If there are, you probably need `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/` in your Apache config too.

Comment: what do you get if you request `app.company.net:3000/` ? Maybe your Node simply isn't configured to respond for `/` ?